# How does one run Spring XD in distributed mode?

Tags: spring-xd

I'm looking to start Spring XD in distributed mode (more specifically deploying it with BOSH). How does the admin component communicate to the module container?

If it's via TCP/HTTP, surely I'll have to tell the admin component where all the containers are? If it's via Redis, I would've thought that I'll need to tell the containers where the Redis instance is?

**Update**

I've tried running `xd-admin` and Redis on one box, and `xd-container` on another with `redis.properties` updated to point to the admin box. The container starts without reporting any exceptions.

Running the example stream submission `curl -d "time | log" http://{admin IP}:8080/streams/ticktock` yields no output to either console, and not output to the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication between the Admin and Container runtime components is via the messaging bus, which by default is Redis.

Make sure the environment variable XD_HOME is set as per the documentation; if it is not you will see a logging message that suggests the properties file has been loaded correctly when it has not:

```
13/06/24 09:20:35 INFO support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer: Loading properties file from URL [file:../config/redis.properties]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the xd-container script, then the redis.properties is expected to be under "XD_HOME/config" where XD_HOME points the base directory where you have bin, config, lib & modules of xd.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Please see updated bug report in JIRA - I'd changed the values in `config/redis.properties` but they were not being used. I've repeated this on three machines, BTW.

Comment: Hi, No problem. Just trying to figure out how you launch your xd-container script and why it is failing to load the redis.properties in your case. As I mentioned in the JIRA, as long as you have "xd.home" system property correctly, the redis.properties under xd.home/config should get loaded. I don't see any other reason why you could not load the redis.properties when you launch the container from xd-container script that comes out of the box. Please check that out and we can track this issues on XD-295.